# Showing Multiple Columns mysql

Tags: mysql, database, join, subquery

I am writing a database using mysql and I am trying to show multiple columns using subquery but it gives me an error "ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)".

the code for the query looks like this:

```
SELECT P_SSN, Name, Blood_Type
FROM PATIENT
WHERE P_SSN IN
 (SELECT P_SSN, ID
  FROM BLOOD_POUCH
  WHERE Blood_Type LIKE 'A');
```

Or in a join

```
SELECT P_SSN, Name, Blood_Type, ID
FROM PATIENT, BLOOD_POUCH
WHERE PATIENT.P_SSN = BLOOD_POUCH.P_SSN
 AND Blood_type LIKE 'A';
```

My tables are:

PATIENT - P_SSN, Name, Blood_Type, ..... 
// P_SSN PK

BLOOD_POUCH - ID, Blood_Type,...., P_SSN 
// ID PK, P_SSN FK

Any ideas on how to display ID as well? If I leave only P_SSN it works, but I'd like the BLOOD_POUCH table to show some information as well.

Comment: check for joining the tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would give you the desired result:

```
  SELECT P.P_SSN, P.NAME, P.BLOOD_TYPE, B.ID
FROM PATIENT P JOIN BLOOD_POUCH B
ON P.P_SSN = B.P_SSN
WHERE B.BLOOD_TYPE LIKE '%A%';
```

Comment: This query will give me a result without the ID column.

Comment: Edited. Can you please check?

Comment: I'm lost. Why 'LIKE'?

Comment: @ Strawberry : She might want to consider blood groups A and AB..;-)

Comment: Correct. I am a guy by the way ha.

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT A.P_SSN, A.NAME, A.BLOOD_TYPE, B.ID
FROM PATIENT A,BLOOD_POUCH B
WHERE A.P_SSN = B.P_SSN
AND B.BLOOD_TYPE LIKE '%A%';
```